# Migrating NUCLEO152RE to STM32L073

Tags: stm32, stm32ldiscovery, stm32l152

I have a code on NUCLEOL152RE i want to migrate this code to STM32L073RZ

What are the step i have to be done to migrate this code from NUCLEO152RE to STM32L073.

Comment: You'll have to tell us a lot more. Let's see: library used for configurations (peripheral, hal, cmis), peripherals used, etc.

Comment: If you code is written using STM32 HAL then it would not be difficult, but we know nothing about your code so it would be difficult to port it.

Comment: I got the code from ARMmbed https://developer.mbed.org/users/spcores/code/TC_Bootcamp_1V1/docs/042ccdf1dd92/SerialDisplay_8cpp_source.html                                             I converted above code  from ARMmbed to KEIL

Comment: i have tried this same code for STM32L073 then i got these error      .\build\uvision5\1_kernelTC_Bootcamp_1V1.axf: Error: L6366E: chainableled.o attributes are not compatible with the provided attributes .
Object chainableled.o contains Build Attributes that are incompatible with the provided attributes.  
Tag_CPU_arch = ARM v7 (=10)
 Tag_CPU_arch_profile = The microcontroller profile 'M' (e.g. for Cortex M3) (=77)

Answer (score 0):

There is significant difference between cores you are switching.

Cortex M0+ doesn't support unaligned access:

"There is no support for unaligned accesses on the Cortex-M0+ processor. Any attempt to 
perform an unaligned memory access operation results in a HardFault exception."

It means that e. g. 4B variable address must be 4-dividable. Is it uncomfortable while parsing protocol frames etc.

Also it doesn't support bitbanding (bit access to memory).